# Link CSS Image Slider to admin panel

Tags: css, slider, gallery

I like this CSS Image Slider but I don't know to link it to the admin panel so it will automatically take the images uploaded there and also add extra bullet for each image uploaded.
If anyone knows how to make this it would be great.
Here is the link for the slider:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-image-slider

Thanks.

Comment: You already have admin panel, or you need to build it?

Comment: I have already a custom admin panel.